# SwiftUI: Popover with List and Button

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to create a Popover with a List and a Button, as display it from a button in the toolbar. I'm testing on MacOS, and I'm seeing the same behaviour on iPadOS.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Popover Test")
        .padding()
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem() {
                Button(action: {showingPopover = true}) {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait.fill")
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    PopoverView()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct PopoverView: View {

    @State var testData = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            List(testData, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Button 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is the List displayed with the Button below it.

However, when the popover is displayed, only the button shows.

[image: With List & Button Code]

If I comment out the button code, the List displays.

[image: With Button code commented out]

How can I get the List and the Button to display?

Xcode 15.1, MacOS 13.6.1

Comment: In your `PopoverView`, try giving the `VStack` a frame, eg `.frame(width: 222, height: 333)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks! That's fixed it. It also works if the .frame() is put onto the List element. 

However, am I right in say that, given the way SwiftUI works, I shouldn't have to use a .frame(), and it looks like a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: yes probably yet another bug. In `PopoverView`, if you replace the `VStack/List` with `ScrollView/ForEach`, then you don't have to use a frame.